# How to properly cleanup Cassandra after stress testing?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've been tasked with standing up and prep'ing our production Cassandra cluster (3.11.1). Everything was fine, loaded in a few hundred million records with the stress testing tool, great. However after I was done I did a "DROP KEYSPACE keyspace1;" (the space used by the stress test) assuming this was like MySQL and the space would be cleaned up.

Now I've run nodetools cleanup, flush, truncatehints, cleansnapshots and just about every other command variation I can find. The disk usage is still ~30GB per node and nothing seems to be going on in Cassandra.

So #1 - How do I recover the diskspace that is being absorbed by the now deleted keyspace?

And #2 - How should I have deleted this data, if this was the "wrong way"?

Comment: `auto_snapshot 
(Default: true) Enables or disables whether Cassandra takes a snapshot of the data before truncating a keyspace or dropping a table. To prevent data loss, Datastax strongly advises using the default setting. If you set auto_snapshot to false, you lose data on truncation or drop.`

see [the docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html?hl=cassandra.yaml%2Cconfiguration%2Cfile)

Answer (score 4):

After you drop the keyspace you can delete its directory in your data directory. Which would clean it up, there isnt a command to do that.

Comment: So if I drop a keyspace that's spread across several dozen servers on several harddrives each... I need to `rm` several hundred files? What does the cleanup/compaction process even do then?

Comment: `rm` 1 directory per node yes, dropping keyspaces and tables never actually deletes the data, thats truncate. cleanup will rewrite the sstables, filtering out any data that does not belong in its token range. Its used for after adding nodes to the cluster, the data that the node used to own is still on disk - cleanup gets rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Chris said, we can manually delete the data. Also to add on to what he said, dropping the data does **NOT** really the data until after a specified `gc_grace_seconds` has passed. Default is 864000 seconds.

We can actually modify this by running this in cqlsh:

`ALTER TABLE keyspace.table WITH gc_grace_seconds = 5;`

And check again with:

`SELECT table_name,gc_grace_seconds FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name='transcript';`